# What is a good CSS cleanup tool?

Tags: css

I am working on a CSS file that is a total mess right now and wanted to clean it up, take a look:

```
...
solid;border-collapse:collapse!important}.account_table_top_text{padding:5px 0 5px 10px}.account_table_header_text{font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif!important;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;color:black}.account_add_account_link{cursor:pointer;text-
...
```

Anyway you got the idea, is there a good tool to clean up CSS files? I just want the file much much cleaner and readable.

Comment: Open source and offline: https://github.com/prettier/prettier

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I always run messy CSS through [this online tool](http://www.lonniebest.com/FormatCSS/). It works wonders for unformatted CSS.

Comment: Wow, great site, it works wonders on really messed up CSS files!

Comment: Cool! Thanks for recommending my tool. I'm actually the guy who made it. Neat to come across this.

Answer (score 2):

Online tool available here:

http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/main/csscompressor/

Comparison of various solutions here:

http://idoblogging.wordpress.com/2007/02/10/comparison-css-cleanupcompressoptimizer-tools/

Answer (score 2):

Try [ProCSSor](http://procssor.com)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.prettyprinter.de/

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in Visual Studio (which you might or might not be - I am fully aware that this might not be the case...) pressing

```
[Ctrl]+[K] - [Ctrl]+[D]
```

will organize any file for you (css, html, c#, vb.net, xml...).

Answer (score 0):

New release of "Dust-ME Selectors" firefox plugin which works for firefox versions 5-9
http://blog.brothersmorrison.com/?p=198

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-roundup/

Answer (score 0):

I like [ProCSSor](http://procssor.com/process), which is available both online and as a Mac app. One of the advantages over FormatCSS, as mentioned by Dan Walker, is that it can indent child selectors, which I think improves readability.