# How to encapsulate CSS, especially for popups and no iframe involved?

Tags: html, css, encapsulation

Just got a new webpage with css for a fancy box popup from the design team;

And they don't know or don't care to look for existing classes and ids;

I need a working solution without any `IFRAME`

The problem is that there are already over 20.000 css lines in the main css file, and at some point something will get overwritten and the entire website will do a big BANG!

This new webpage has very common `class` and `id` names, and I am talking about almost 100 tags with css properties;

I want to know if there is a method to `encapsulate` this new css properties and the future ones;

And if there is a way to do this, how can it be done?

With this webpage I got lucky, I pasted the tags with content and just before this, I used the `style type"text/css'` tag; But i will not always be lucky;

Just because we get webpages with css code written by different people, it does not seam fair to me to create new css classes if some of the properties or names or ids intersect with each other.

I now have about 10 classes for the `a tag` and im most part, the properties are the same;

Comment: The easiest way to encapsulate stuff like this is put it in an `iframe`.

Comment: that's the point, it cant be a iframe in this case

Comment: The `scoped` attribute could help (see [sample here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/style) and more info [here](http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/)) but achieving full separation is going to be difficult/impossible with the constraints you described. And 20K CSS lines? that's pretty scary.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no clean way to do this inside the same document. To exclude a certain class from the 20k CSS rules, you'd have to touch those rules. If that's not possible, your only way out is to make  *your* CSS override *every single rule* that the 20k CSS rules define.

Comment: I thought that there is a simple way, like a reset class or something; I used a reset class with a bookmarklet a couple of times and it worked; but with 20k lines, its difficult now;

Comment: A reset would only work if it's more specific than all other rules. You can't guarantee that. You could create super-expensive selectors (eg, 5 ID selectors in a row), which is bad. You could also use `!important` after every rule, which is even worse. Either way, you can't guarantee your code won't be messed with.

Comment: Not sure if they would allow you to clean up the CSS but you might look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890646/what-is-a-good-css-cleanup-tool and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449145/css-refactoring-tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use targeted rules and let the cascade take care of it for you. Put your popup in a wrapper with as detailed of a name as you like.

```
<div id="myPopupDivWithCommonIds">
    <!-- rest of popup -->
</div>
```

And target your css rules to that div.

```
#myPopupDivWithCommonIds .error { color: bright-pink; }
#myPopupDivWithCommonIds #main { width: 93.21%; }
```

Etc. etc. This takes care of the css rules and prevents your new stuff from overflowing. You will have to take care to make sure none of the other rules trickle down; the best way for that is to judiciously overwrite any properties that are defined (what Pekka said). You could also go nuclear on it and include a custom 'reboot' or 'bootstrap' stylesheet and again re-target all of its rules to your new popup div (like you said, it's difficult for 20k lines of css; but including another file with the resets rules targeted to your div by appending the #id selector as above helps a little).

Oh, and that still doesn't address the problem of repeated ids technically being invalid markup and very likely to interfere with any JavaScript you're trying to run on that page.

If this sounds like a mess, well, it is. Your developers and designers have got it to that point and short of a serious refactoring, you're not going to get back to a clean solution. An iFrame may seem like a hack or impossible for your use case, but it really would clean up a lot of your correctly foreseen problems.

Comment: i have the webpage, i opened a fancy box widget in a iframe and in this iframe i opened a fancy box popup; its a total mess, and if more code is written, the bang will be heard even by the martians

Comment: Poor form to link youtube on a programming site, but I can't help myself: [Martian Kaboom!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8rYotiiFP8)

Comment: what? I dont understand what you say;

Comment: It's just a funny cartoon clip from my childhood - I was reminded of it by your comment. The character is 'Marvin the Martian'.